# Which icon is Opera mobile using for bookmarks / speeddial

Tags: favicon

Which icon is Opera mobile using for bookmarks / speeddial?

I've generated all possible icons using this converter:
http://www.favicon-generator.org/ and included them with the correct tags in my website head.

The converter generates "icons for Web, Android, Microsoft, and iOS (iPhone and iPad) Apps" - well it truly does, it created a total of 25 different icon formats / sizes for my web site.

Sadly Opera mobile seems to use the most low-res version it can find among these 25 icons. It looks horrible in the speeddial / bookmarks.

But I haven't yet been able to figure out, which exact icon it is using, all help would be appreciated. Which icon does Opera mobile use?

UPDATE: By trial and error, I found Opera Mobile uses the "favicon.ico", even though there are higher resolution icons available for my website, and I've embeded them with this code:

```
<!--Favicons-->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/apple-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/apple-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/apple-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/apple-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/apple-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/apple-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/apple-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/apple-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/apple-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/android-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/favicon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/manifest.json">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/ms-icon-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"> 
<!--End Favicons-->
```

Comment: Why do you care?   Opera mini has very low usage numbers.   I can't imagine that many of your web site users would run into this problem.

Comment: Opera Mobile is not Opera Mini. Opera Mobile has more than 100. Million downloads in Google Play Store, so I might care.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, another hour of trial and error, I think I finally found the answer.

The problem is caused by this code:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/apple-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/apple-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/apple-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/apple-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/apple-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/apple-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/apple-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/apple-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/apple-icon-180x180.png">
```

I have to use a precomposed icon definition like this:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="https://***/wp-content/themes/***/favicons/apple-icon-152x152.png">
```

That alone won't make it work. I had to erase the first block of code, so Opera's finally using the high-res icon. That's not fully satisfying as I now have to disregard all other resolutions.